# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.Mvc.RedirectToRouteResult' to 'System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-2

How can i Redirect To Action from JsonResult to ActionResult but i m getting error. my error is "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.Mvc.RedirectToRouteResult' to 'System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult'".
My Code

Json Result:

```
   public JsonResult AddTruckExpensesTransactionChild(string totaldays, string amount)
   {
        string Mess = objActive.Save();
        if (Mess == "1")
        {
            return RedirectToAction("GetTruckExpensesChild", new { id="", sid="" });
        }
        return Json(Mess, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
   }
```

ActionResult:

```
    public ActionResult GetTruckExpensesChild(string id, string sid)
    {
        TruckExpensesTransactionClass Transaction = new TruckExpensesTransactionClass();
        if (sid != null)
        {                
            Transaction.TransactionChild = objActive.ShowTransactionChild(id, sid);
            return View(Transaction);
        }
        else
        {                
            return View(Transaction);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use base class **ActionResult** so that you can return **View**,**JSON**,**Content** or **Partial View**:

```
public ActionResult AddTruckExpensesTransactionChild(string totaldays, string amount)
   {
        string Mess = objActive.Save();
        if (Mess == "1")
              return Json(new { Url = Url.Action("GetTruckExpensesChild", new { id = "", sid = "" }) });

        return Json(Mess, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
   }
```

But if you are calling this action via ajax you have to redirect to that action via javascript because returning `RedirectToAction` will return the html in response of ajax but not a redirect.

So you need to return action url via json with some flag and check that if response has that flag, redirect to that url via jquery.

In Ajax call success check if its url:

```
success: function(result) {
          if(result.Url.length > 0)
{
        window.location.href=result.Url;
}
```

Comment: Yes this Code is return to that action but my page is not redirected.

Comment: you have to return the url on which you want to redirect and redirect via jquery

Comment: i cannot understand do you show me sample code please because  m new to jquery

Comment: No Friend Its Not Working

Comment: put ``alert(result)`` to check what is returned

Comment: Yes Friend the URl is Coming but mess is not coming that why its not reloaded and its Redirect thank you so much friend. . .

Comment: mess will not come as if Mess is 1 we return only url where it should redirect

Answer (score 3):

The [`JsonResult`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.jsonresult%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) class implements the `ActionResult` class. Just change the `JsonResult` to `ActionResult` as return type for your action method:

```
public ActionResult AddTruckExpensesTransactionChild(string totaldays, string amount)
{
    string Mess = objActive.Save();
    if (Mess == "1")
    {
        return RedirectToAction("GetTruckExpensesChild", new { id="", sid="" });
    }
    return Json(Mess, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: Yes this Code is return to that action but my page is not redirected.