# Passing List of String type with RedirectToAction in ASP.NET-MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

This code is used to pass a `List<String>` with `RedirectToAction` method:

```
public List<String> ListOfBrandNames(string id)
    {
        var result = db.Items.Where(x => x.Category.Name.Equals(id)).Select(x => x.BrandID).ToList();
        var ListOfBrands = db.Brands.Where(t => result.Contains(t.BrandID)).ToList();
        List<String> BrandNames = ListOfBrands.Select(f => f.Name.ToString()).ToList();
        return RedirectToAction("BrandsOfACategory", new { brands = BrandNames });
    }
```

`RedirectToAction` method is throwing this error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.Mvc.RedirectToRootResult' to 'System.Collection.Generic.List'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.Mvc.RedirectToRouteResult' to 'System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24008137/cannot-implicitly-convert-type-system-web-mvc-redirecttorouteresult-to-system)

Comment: 2 answers given on your provided list. Both confirm each other so I implemented and checked but getting this error: `Server Error in '/' Application.
The resource cannot be found.
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 

Requested URL: /Home/ListOfBrandNames

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.7.3282.0` in the browser. Please remove duplicate

Answer (score 1):

You're using wrong return type on the action method, since [`RedirectToAction`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) requires return type of `ActionResult` instead of `List<string>` because [`RedirectToRouteResult`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.redirecttorouteresult?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) inherited from `ActionResult`.

**Update:**

You need to serialize the list into JSON string to pass it smoothly (with `Newtonsoft.Json` library), so the target action method must use `string` parameter. Here is the correct setup to send list of brands to another action method:

```
public ActionResult ListOfBrandNames(string id)
{
    var result = db.Items.Where(x => x.Category.Name.Equals(id)).Select(x => x.BrandID).ToList();
    var ListOfBrands = db.Brands.Where(t => result.Contains(t.BrandID)).ToList();
    return RedirectToAction("BrandsOfACategory", new { brands = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ListOfBrands) });
}
```

And the target controller action should be look like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult BrandsOfACategory(string brands)
{
    var listOfBrands = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Brand>>(brands);

    List<string> BrandNames = listOfBrands.Select(f => f.Name.ToString()).ToList();

    // do something and return view
}
```

Reference:

[How to pass List in Redirecttoaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12108770/how-to-pass-list-in-redirecttoaction)

Comment: Throwing exception: `Message: "Self referencing loop detected for property 'Brand' with type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Brand_6F41EA48F10B0AC41C001572E51DD1493029140C74DC2BC1D4D6FFE059AB59EC'. Path '[0].Items[0]'." string` on line `return RedirectToAction("BrandsOfACategory", new { brands = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ListOfBrands) });` in the first action method code you have given above.

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code,

```
public List<String> ListOfBrandNames(string id)
{
    var result = db.Items.Where(x => x.Category.Name.Equals(id)).Select(x => x.BrandID).ToList();
    var ListOfBrands = db.Brands.Where(t => result.Contains(t.BrandID)).ToList();
    List<String> BrandNames = ListOfBrands.Select(f => f.Name.ToString()).ToList();
    TempData["Brands"]=BrandNames;
    return RedirectToAction("BrandsOfACategory");
}
```

After then you can fetch data from TempData to list of string in "BrandsOfACategory" method.